# Format Load Data before render in Extjs 3.4

Tags: javascript, extjs3

I am opening a form window, it load data from service and get the response.

```
form: {
    url: reqUrl('users', 'save'),
    loadUrl: reqUrl('users', 'form'),
    padding: '0 0 0 0',
    items: User.formTabPanel
  }
```

I am getting data by LoadUrl, Now I want to format this data before its render. 
Can anyone give me some idea, how do I do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a listener for beforerender you could grab the loadURL data, run it through your formatting method then use 
`form.getStore().proxy.setUrl('.../url', false);`
.. the second parameter is for whether you want to make the url permanent.